How can I use MacTeX without being root?
I have a fresh install of MacTeX 2024.  From the FAQ I gather that the binaries are supposed to be available under the symlink /Library/TeX/texbin.

MacTeX installs a symbolic link to the TeX Live binaries named /Library/TeX/texbin

So I attempt to test my new install by running /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex:
amoe@macbook $ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
zsh: permission denied: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex

If I show the permissions of /Library/TeX they are quite restrictive.
root@macbook # ls -ld /Library/TeX
drwxr-x---  7 root  wheel  224 31 Oct 09:33 /Library/TeX

Am I supposed to be able to use the MacTeX binaries as a non-root user?  I have already tried removing and reinstalling MacTeX without any effect.

I have drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel             320 14 Mar  2024 TeX: exactly what did you download? How exactly did you install?

If you installed MacTeX as root, you're doomed. Never login as root on MacOS.

@JosephWright I downloaded the file linked here.

I installed as my regular user by clicking the package file, but I was prompted for my root password when installing.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Did you use sudo? Please advise.

@Mico The installer is a GUI - it asks for elevated permissions but not as sudo from the Terminal

@amoe Something is very odd - I think this might be one for the MacTeX mailing list, as you'll get the core MacTeX developers there

I'm pretty sure that MacTeX always installs as root. Thus one would need to do sudp tlmgr update --all --self in order to update it.

@daleif Ys, but the binaries are supposed to be usable as a normal user :)

@JosephWright ahh, I was reading egregs, yes then the OPs look fishy.

This was due to a globally mandated restrictive umask setting applied by my institution.  Mine was set to 027.
After setting the umask back to 022 the installer worked as expected, so if anyone sees this, check your umask.
